# Create dynamic text box id

Tags: jquery

I want to create dynamic text box id on click event of button using jquery. I have created a function that creates three text boxes when I click on a button. What I require is, every text box should have it unique ID.

Here is the function :-

```
function CreateTextBox(value) {
    return '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="col-md-3"><label>Ingredients</label><input class="form-control"name = "text1" id="ring" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;</div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-3"><label>Quantity</label><input class="form-control"name = "text2" type="text" id="rqty" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;</div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-3"><label>Measure Unit</label><input class="form-control"name = "text3" id="runit" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;</div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-3"><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-info remove" id="rm"/></div></div>' 

}
```

This code works fine for me for the first time. When I run this function for the second time I need different Id(like ring1,rqty1,runit1)

Answer (score 1):

you could add a class to the created parent div (for example `<div class="col-md-12 createdBoxes">`) and then in the function you get the number of these using:

```
var number=$('.createdBoxes').length+1;
```

and then add that number to the dynamically created fields id so each  id would be like `id="qty'+number+'"` and on each call to the function the length would increase so you would have an index of the number of dynamically created divs.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some kind of increment value to keep track of how many times the button was pushed (say, something like `var round = 0;`).  Then for each time you add the inputs you can have the ids look like `'id="rqty'+ round+ '"'`.